# C visual studio undeclared identifier for define

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

Hello i have the following code..

```
#define VB_CHAR     signed char
#define VB_UCHAR    unsigned char

#if defined(VBISAM_NO_CISAM_CONFLICT)
    #include "vbisam_rename.h"
#endif

#include    "vbdecimal.h"
```

vbdecimal doesnt include any other header but fails to see it

Error   1   error C2065: 'VB_CHAR' : undeclared identifier  c:\users\parhs\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testdll4\vbdecimal.h

I have to define VB_CHAR in vbdecimal in order to work..
Any work-around for this?

Comment: Are you sure this is the only place in your project that `vbdecimal.h` is being included?  Are you sure that `vbisam_rename.h` isn't `#undef`-ing `VB_CHAR`?

Answer (score 0):

Well. It could be that vbisam_rename.h '#undefs' VB_CHAR.